# Закрывать видео, при закрытии окна.

Tags: java, javafx, видео, videoview

Доброе утро!

Нужна помощь по обработке событий. Проблема заключается в том, что у меня есть программа, в которой есть видео. Видео открывается в отдельном окне. Пир закрытие окна, видео продолжает проигрывать. Побывал прописать отключение но все время выдает ошибку. Как решить данную проблему? Буду искренне благодарен за помощь.

Comment: покажи как отключаешь поток с видео

Answer (score 0):

Закинуть листнер на закрытие окна, и в нем же реализовать отключение потока видео

Answer (score 0):

Сделать так, чтобы убить или поток или программу):

```
stage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> {
    //тут убиваешь поток с видео 
    //ну или закрываешь программу так)
    System.exit(-1);
});
```